# SwiftMailer can not send TemplatedEmail , symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer

here is what swiftmailer says, despite the symfony 4 docs saying we cound send such TemplatedEmail object, it is not possible:

> Argument 1 passed to Swift_Mailer::send() must be an instance of
>   Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage, instance of
>   Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail given, called in
>   /home/tk/html/src/Service/MailService.php on line 103

code to send my html mail inside my MailService:

```
// ...
use Swift_Mailer;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;

class MailService {

// ...

public function sendOwnerPollsAction( Owner $foundOwner ) {

        // anti spam , limit to every minute TODO
//      $lastSend = $admin_user->getRequestedPollsDate();
//      $now      = new \DateTime();

//      if ( date_diff( $lastSend, $now ) < 60 ) {
//          // too soon!
//          die( 'too soon!' );
//      }
//      $admin_user->setRequestedPollsDate( $now );
//      $em->persist( $admin_user );
//      $em->flush();
        $titleEmail = 'Framadate | Mes sondages';

        $templateVars = [
            'owner'          => $foundOwner,
            'title'          => $titleEmail,
            'email_template' => 'emails/owner-list.html.twig',
        ];

        $email = ( new TemplatedEmail() )
            ->from( 'ne-pas-repondre@framadate-api.cipherbliss.com' )
            ->to( new Address( $foundOwner->getEmail() ) )
            ->subject( $titleEmail )
            ->htmlTemplate( $templateVars[ 'email_template' ] )
            ->context( $templateVars );

        // send email
        return $this->mailer->send( $email );
    }
```

the swiftmailer doc for symfony 4 says we can send mails like that, and that templatedemail extend Email.
https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/mailer.html#creating-sending-messages
so i don't get how we could send templated html emails.

packages:

```
"symfony/framework-bundle": "4.3.*",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.4",
"php": "^7.1.3",
```

Comment: [`Symfony Mailer`](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/mailer.html), introduced in 4.3, is not the same as [`Swift Mailer`](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html). If you want to keep using Swift, you can inject twig `Environment` into your service and render the template manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing Symfony Mailer with Swift Mailer.

TemplatedEmail is from **Symfony**Mailer, but you are trying to send with **Swift**Mailer. Therefore the error.

If you truly want to use Swift Mailer then require your TemplateEmail Section.

Auszug von [SwiftMailer for Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html) :

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message($titleEmail))
        ->setFrom('ne-pas-repondre@framadate-api.cipherbliss.com')
        ->setTo(new Address( $foundOwner->getEmail() ))
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'emails/owner-list.html.twig',
                [
                'title'          => $titleEmail,
                'email_template' => 'emails/owner-list.html.twig'
                ]
            ),
            'text/html'
        )

$mailer->send($message);
```

If you want to use TemplatedEmail with **Symfony**Mailer, then follow [Mailer on Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html). There is additional config to be done.